# Disable click on whole row in angular mat table

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a `mat-table` with whole row click:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="clickHandler(row)"></tr>
```

And I have click on certain row in this table:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="test">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> test </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (click)="getRecord(row)"> {{row.test}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

How I can disable click on whole `row((click)="clickHandler(row)")` when I click on certain
cell `(click)="getRecord(row);`

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What do you mean by whole Row? How you can click on whole row of table?

Comment: <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="clickHandler(row)"></tr> let click me on whole row

Comment: Sounds like `event.stopPropagation()` could be useful here (if you want to trigger the click event of the ng-container but not that of the whole row), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: You said `when i click on certain row` I think you mean certain cell? Yes?

Comment: yeah that what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `$event` to `getRecord` method and call `stopPropagation();` of the event:

```
 getRecord(row,$event){
       $event.stopPropagation();
       ....
  }
```

And in your HTML:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" (click)="getRecord(row,$event)">
```

Here is working sample I create for you: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ywrjj?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)